# Reduce left outer join in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

Updated with sqlfilld [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a835c0/1)

I have an Oracle query where I need to reduce the number of *left outer join* to perform efficiently. The current query runs for more than 2 hours and I want to reduce its complexity by reducing the number of join operations.

Without the joins, the query runs in 15 minutes. Hence I want to rewrite the logic. Is there any efficient way to do that?

```
WITH myquery AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM TEST_FILE1
)
SELECT 
    A.Col3, A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col4, A.Col5
  --  D.CB,
  --  NVL(D.CD, 0), NVL(D.CE, 0), NVL(D.EF, 0),
    ,CASE WHEN V1.Col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS QQ1
    ,CASE WHEN V2.Col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS QQ2
    ,CASE WHEN V3.Col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS QQ3
    ,CASE WHEN V4.Col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS QQ4
, case when V5.Col1 is NULL then 0 else 1 end as QQ5
, case when V6.Col3 is NULL then 0 else 1 end as QQ6
, case when V7.Col1 is NULL then 0 else 1 end as QQ7
, case when V8.Col3 is NULL then 0 else 1 end as QQ8
FROM (
  SELECT Col3, Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5 
  FROM (
    SELECT distinct Col3
    FROM myquery
  ) A1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT distinct Col1
    FROM myquery
  ) A2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT distinct Col2
    FROM myquery
  ) A3
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT distinct Col4
    FROM myquery
  ) A4
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT distinct Col5
    FROM myquery
  ) A5
  WHERE Col3 = 42
) A
LEFT JOIN myquery D on NVL(D.Col3, '-') = NVL(A.Col3, '-') AND NVL(D.Col1, '-') = NVL(A.Col1, '-') 
    AND NVL(D.Col2, '-') = NVL(A.Col2, '-') AND NVL(D.Col4, '-') = NVL(A.Col4, '-') AND NVL(D.Col5, 
'-') = NVL(A.Col5, '-')
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col1, Col3, Col5
  FROM myquery
) V1 on V1.Col1 = A.Col1 AND V1.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V1.Col5 = A.Col5
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col5, Col2
  FROM myquery
) V2 on V2.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V2.Col5 = A.Col5 AND V2.Col2 = A.Col2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col5, Col1, Col2
  FROM myquery
) V3 on V3.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V3.Col5 = A.Col5 AND V3.Col1 = A.Col1 AND V3.Col2 = A.Col2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col5, Col2
  FROM myquery
  WHERE Col1 in ('Bert','Myra')
) V4 on V4.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V4.Col5 = A.Col5 AND V4.Col2 = A.Col2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col1, Col3
  FROM myquery
) V5 on V5.Col1 = A.Col1 AND V5.Col3 = A.Col3
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col2
  FROM myquery
) V6 on V6.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V6.Col2 = A.Col2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col1, Col2
  FROM myquery
) V7 on V7.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V7.Col1 = A.Col1 AND V7.Col2 = A.Col2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT distinct Col3, Col2
  FROM myquery
  WHERE Col1 in ('Bert','Myra')
) V8 on V8.Col3 = A.Col3 AND V8.Col2 = A.Col2
```

So far I was thinking of using analytical window function but didn't get the desired output .Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Here is my input data of test_file table

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| Bert | "M"  | 42   | 68   | 166  |
| Carl | "M"  | 32   | 70   | 155  |
| Dave | "M"  | 39   | 72   | 167  |
| Elly | "F"  | 30   | 66   | 124  |
| Fran | "F"  | 33   | 66   | 115  |
| Hank | "M"  | 30   | 71   | 158  |
| Jake | "M"  | 32   | 69   | 143  |
| Luke | "M"  | 34   | 72   | 163  |
| Neil | "M"  | 36   | 75   | 160  |
| Page | "F"  | 31   | 67   | 135  |
| Alex | "M"  | 41   | 74   | 170  |
| Gwen | "F"  | 26   | 64   | 121  |
| Ivan | "M"  | 53   | 72   | 175  |
| Kate | "F"  | 47   | 69   | 139  |
| Myra | "F"  | 23   | 62   | 98   |
| Omar | "M"  | 38   | 70   | 145  |
| Quin | "M"  | 29   | 71   | 176  |
| Ruth | "F"  | 28   | 65   | 131  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

From this table I want to create every posssible combination by taking distinct values of each column by applying cross join . It will produce 7776 records with my filter on `col1=42` . because I want all possible combination for this column only.

With this combination I want to check which all column combinatios are null using many combinations of left outer joins.

**Output(partial):**

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| COL3 | COL1 | COL2 | COL4 | COL5 | QQ1 | QQ2 | QQ3 | QQ4 | QQ5 | QQ6 | QQ7 | QQ8 |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 42   | Page | "F"  | 68   | 176  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Alex | "F"  | 62   | 143  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Fran | "M"  | 66   | 175  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Omar | "F"  | 70   | 176  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Elly | "M"  | 72   | 124  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Quin | "M"  | 64   | 160  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Omar | "M"  | 64   | 158  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Kate | "F"  | 62   | 176  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Neil | "F"  | 69   | 145  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Dave | "F"  | 62   | 163  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 42   | Ruth | "M"  | 70   | 115  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Bert | "M"  | 65   | 121  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 42   | Bert | "M"  | 72   | 145  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 42   | Omar | "M"  | 62   | 158  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
| 42   | Ruth | "M"  | 75   | 131  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Sample data and output would be helpful

Comment: Sample data and desired output **and** a description of the task would be helpful. Even assuming that your current query is correct (which we don't know), the best we can do is to guess your problem requirement from the code; a form of reverse engineering that is a complete waste of time and prone to errors. Tell us WHAT the query is SUPPOSED to do, in addition to showing the query you tried.

Comment: @mathguy I have updated with input sample data.

Comment: @Avi I have updated the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking whether data exists in a table we use `EXISTS` or `IN`, not `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ...)`. Hence this is the query I'd probably come up with:

```
WITH myquery AS
(
  SELECT * FROM TEST_FILE1
)
, a as
(
  select col1, col2, 42 as col3, col4, col5
  from
  (
    (select distinct col1 from myquery)
      cross join
    (select distinct col2 from myquery)
      cross join
    (select distinct col4 from myquery)
      cross join
    (select distinct col5 from myquery)
  )
)
select
  a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5,
  case when (col1, col3, col5)       in (select col1, col3, col5       from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v1,
  case when (col2, col3, col5)       in (select col2, col3, col5       from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v2,
  case when (col1, col2, col3, col5) in (select col1, col2, col3, col5 from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v3,
  case when (col2, col3, col5)       in (select col2, col3, col5       from myquery where col1 in ('Bert', 'Myra')) then 1 else 0 end as v4,
  case when (col1, col3)             in (select col1, col3             from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v5,
  case when (col2, col3)             in (select col2, col3             from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v6,
  case when (col1, col2, col3)       in (select col1, col2, col3       from myquery                               ) then 1 else 0 end as v7,
  case when (col2, col3)             in (select col2, col3             from myquery where col1 in ('Bert', 'Myra')) then 1 else 0 end as v8
from a
order by a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, a.col5;
```

If your real query here: `WITH myquery AS (...)` is more than just a mere `SELECT * FROM TEST_FILE1`, you may want to use the `/*+MATERIALIZE*/` hint here in order to speed up access to it.

Comment: Thanks you so much for detailed query . In my query I need few columns from myquery and via left outer join as below LEFT JOIN myquery D on NVL(D.Col3, '-') = `NVL(A.Col3, '-') AND NVL(D.Col1, '-') = NVL(A.Col1, '-') 
    AND NVL(D.Col2, '-') = NVL(A.Col2, '-') AND NVL(D.Col4, '-') = NVL(A.Col4, '-') AND NVL(D.Col5, 
'-') = NVL(A.Col5, '-')` . If I try to include the above leftouter join in your modified query the query runs forever . interestingly If I remove the left youter join i am getting records in few seconds .

Comment: This is because you are invoking functions on the columns. The DBMS doesn't understand what you are doing and scans the whole table for every row. One way to go about this may be to make your intentions clear with `ON (d.col1 = a.col1 OR (d.col1 IS NULL AND a.col1 IS NULL)) AND (d.col2 = a.col2 OR (d.col2 IS NULL AND a.col2 IS NULL) ...)`. (In standard SQL we would write `d.col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM a.col1 AND d.col2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM a.col2`, but Oracle doesn't support this yet.)

Comment: Another common way is to provide function indexes on the tables and expressions in question: `create index idx1 on d (NVL(d.col1, '-'), NVL(d.col2, '-'), NVL(d.col3, '-'), NVL(d.col3, '-'))`, but as `A` is just an ad-hoc view and not a table, you cannot create an index on it. Well, maybe the index on table `D` suffices, because it still helps the DBMS to find its rows faster. I prefer the plain version with ` ON (d.col1 = a.col1 OR (d.col1 IS NULL AND a.col1 IS NULL)) AND ...`, though. So, if that solves the performance issue. I'd go with that.